# how to make a properties file available after building a java application

Tags: java, swing, properties-file

I'm developing a java swing application and it works fine, but after building my app , when I run the jar file , my app doesn't works as I want. so to know what's the problem I used this test :

```
FileReader reader;
Properties props;
    try{
         reader = new FileReader("src\\inputs.properties");
         props = new Properties();
         props.load(reader2);

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,reader.getClass());
  }catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
  }
```

so when i run the app it works fine and i get this message : 
[message before building the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DrzN.png)

And that means that my properties file is loaded.

But when I build the app, when I run it I get this message :

[message after building the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7y88.png)

My problem is how to make my properties file works after building may app?

I'm using netbeans and this is my project structure :

-source Package
 --default package
  -- inputs.properties
  --myapppackage
  --myapppackage.java

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post error messages as text instead of links to screenshots?

Comment: yes , this the first message :  class java.io.FileReader second message src\inputs.properties (The system cannot find the Path specified)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Java property files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a folder "config" in your project and place the inputs.properties into it.

```
 reader = new FileReader("config/inputs.properties");
```

for details, you can also go through this thread: 
[Netbeans FileReader FileNotFound Exception when the file is in folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091898/netbeans-filereader-filenotfound-exception-when-the-file-is-in-folder)

Or:
When your resourse is in JAR file, it's not a File anymore. A File is only a physical file on the filesystem. Solution: use getResourceAsStream. Something like this:

```
try {

        Properties props;
        Property p=new Property();
        InputStreamReader  in=new InputStreamReader(p.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config/" + "inputs.properties"));
        props = new Properties();

        props.load(in);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, in.getClass());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this to load the file of properties:

```
        File file = new File("inputs.properties);//use the right path
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(fileInput);
        fileInput.close();
```

Comment: Hey , abdelhak, thanks for your response , i change the path  to "inputs.properties" but now get this message :  The system cannot find the path specified. before and after building the app.

Comment: @Ali you the message in both cases?

Comment: @Ali take alook at the answer above

Comment: thanks Abdelhak for your response and your time , but now im sure that i have a problem with the right path to my properties file. so how to load the file, File file = new File("path"); i put the properties file in my  sources package, and i want my properties file be included in main jar of my app, because i want to run the app in other machine. thanks